# Notation of the Dynamic Querying Associations

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-orm

In the [latest documentation of Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html), we can read:

Querying Associations. Associations can also be used within queries:

```
def author = Author.findByName("Stephen King")

def books = author ? Book.findAllByAuthor(author) : []
```

I'd like to know what is the meaning of `?` and `: []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorthand `if` statement in `Groovy` (and `Java`, see the first comment).

```
def books = author ? Book.findAllByAuthor(author) : []
```

is equivalent of:

```
def books
if (author) {
    books = Book.findAllByAuthor(author)
}
else {
    books = []
}
```

See the `elvis operator` (`Groovy` only, not `Java`) [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators).

Comment: This is Java ternary operator and not specific to Groovy. Yes, Elvis operator was added in Groovy.

Comment: and `[]` is Groovy shorthand for `new ArrayList()` (similarly `[:]` means `new LinkedHashMap()`)